# Android wifimanager reset all settings

Tags: android

I tried to create an application for wifi connection. After running some piece of code, i can't even connect my phone to the wifi. I have this piece of code

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", "XXX");
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)fragmentActivity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

The method addNetWork() always returns -1. I'd like to know what piece of code I have to write to reset all wifi settings to find my wifi back.